# Preventing process context switching on Android

Tags: android, c++, process, scheduling, preemption

Now this may seem a bit extreme. I am curious if there would be a way to prevent an application's process from being pre-empted by the Android OS. I have time critical testing in C++ which can varying in results depending if the OS gives the context to another process, which in this case are native processes outside my control.

Is there a way to guarantee process control for at least a given period of time? (such as specifically defining the processes time slice) I've stumbled upon some  [documentation](https://github.com/keesj/gomo/wiki/AndroidScheduling)  which hints at control over the dynamic priority of background process but I'm not sure if this is a guaranteed and/or safe way of doing this since I'd be overriding defines within threads.h

Any ideas? Creative solutions are welcomed.